# How to open activity to certain tab?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have a Main Activity which a FragmentActivity and I have three fragments which are on three separate tabs. On fragment two, I have a button which opens an an activity on which the user can click OK or cancel. Right now when he clicks OK or cancel nothing happens and it just quits the application.

What I would like it to do, is that in onClick() (of either the OK or cancel buttons) of the activity that was opened from the fragment, it goes back to the original activity and back to the same fragment it was on, in this case fragment two.

I right now I have it so that it goes back to the original activity but the first fragment, not the one from which the button was pressed...how can I accomplish this? Here is what I have to go back to the original activity:

```
btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

    //execute background task for processing
    new SaveDetails().execute();  //this actually calls an HTTPRequest

    Intent a = new Intent(ACTIVITY_Edit_Trip.this, ACTIVITY_MAIN_CONTROLLER.class);
    startActivity(a);
}
});
```

The tabs are working fine and i can swipe between them, I just don't know how to go back to a specific one from an activity. Is this possible?

Thanks for the help! If I need to post my PagerAdapter code, I can do that, just let me know!

Edit: I have two activities, the main activity and an edit activity. My main activity is a FragmentActivity which is also the one that creates the tabs where the fragments live one. The edit activity is accessed only when the user presses a button from fragment 2.

Once the button on fragment two is pressed, the edit activity opens and it has two buttons OK and cancel, if the user presses either it should go back to the main activity > fragment 2. Right now with the code I have posted, it goes to main activity > fragment 1.

Comment: its not clear from which activity/fragment you want to navigate to which activity?

Comment: See edit in original post, let me know if that makes more sense!

Comment: use `startActivityForResult` and  display fragment 2 in the second tab

Comment: Not sure what you mean, after reading the documentation for that method, how do I tell it to display fragment 2 instead of going to fragment 1? Right now it opens fragment 1 on tab 1, I want it to open to tab 2...